# How does OpenGL know what type each vertex buffer object is?

Tags: opengl, vertex-buffer, vertex-array

I've just read through a tutorial about Vertex Array Objects and Vertex Buffer Objects, and I can't work out from the following code how OpenGL knows the first VBO (`vertexBufferObjID[0]`) represents vertex coordinates, and the second VBO (`vertexBufferObjID[1]`) represents colour data?

```
glGenBuffers(2, vertexBufferObjID);

// VBO for vertex data
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObjID[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9*sizeof(GLfloat), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0); 
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

// VBO for colour data
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObjID[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9*sizeof(GLfloat), colours, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

**Edit:** Thanks to Peter's answer, I found the following two lines of code which hook up each VBO with the shaders (indices 0 & 1 correlate to the VBO index):

```
glBindAttribLocation(programId, 0, "in_Position");
glBindAttribLocation(programId, 1, "in_Color");
```

Comment: hello would you be so kind as to share the tutorial you mentioned?

Comment: I can't remember it off the top of my head, but I think I googled for something like "OpenGL 3 tutorial".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't, you have to tell it which is which in the shader.

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 color;

void main()
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Ah, I've found the calls to glBindAttribLocation, which uses the indices of 0 and 1, for "in_Position" and "in_Colour" respectively. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`glVertexAttribPointer` is only meant to be used with shaders. Therefore you, as the shader writer, always know what each attribute index is supposed to do, as it maps to a certain variable in your vertex shader. You control the index to variable map with commands `glBindAttribLocation` or `glGetAttribLocation`, or from special keywords inside GLSL.

If you're just using the fixed function pipeline (default shader), then you don't want to use `glVertexAttribPointer`. Instead for the fixed function pipe the equivalent commands are `glVertexPointer` and `glColorPointer`, etc. Note that these are deprecated commands.

Also note that for fixed function `glEnableVertexAttribArray` is to be replaced with `glEnableClientState`.